#  needed in java stored procedure with OUT parameter for MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to create a java program for connection with mysql database.  I want to use stored procedure with 1 out parameter and 1 in parameter.

How to retrieve result using java?  Is there any working example?

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL documentation "Basic JDBC Concepts" page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html) seems to have lots of detailed examples. Have you tried those? If you've tried but are having problems, please post some code.